# Пример аддона для Firefox, использующего content script (как в расширениях Chrome)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-extension

Есть какой-то простой пример, как исполнять content script (как в Chrome) на страницах сайта example.com.

Не могу разобраться, с этими SDK и прочим. В Хроме все просто.

Пожалуйста, никаких Firefox XUL элементов.

Comment: Если честно, мне просто нужен пример расширения. В FF все очень запутано с созданием расширения, а примеры, которые я находил, добавляют кнопку в тулбар (уже не работает, к слову), но того, что мне надо, там нет... :(

Comment: А что вам надо, чего там нет? P.S. Пример с кнопкой очень даже работает.

Answer (score 2):

Вам повезло, и в Mozilla примерно год назад решили повторить API хрома (называется ["web extensions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), сейчас в "experimental alpha state", обещают к Firefox 48 благословить эту фичу и назвать ее стабильной.)

В частности, вот простой пример с content script:
https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/borderify